# How can I have two Window forms, from different projects, show and hide each other?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, circular-dependency

[image: when i click on "opens testing2" it goes to form1 of testing2]

this is the code for Form1.cs of testing file:

```
        Testing2.Form1 t2 = new Testing2.Form1();
        t2.Show();
        this.Hide();
```

When i click on "back to testing" i want Form1.cs of Testing to open.I tried to add reference on Testing2 it gives the following error:
[image]

Comment: If it's circular that means you will need to extract it into a separate project/library and have both reference that.

Comment: i have already combined both the projects into Testing

Comment: Do you mean the `Testing` project or the `Testing` **solution**?

Comment: The error is clearly about the *projects* not the forms. You tried to add the `Testing` project as a reference to `Testing2` when `Testing` already has a reference to `Testing. You can't have two projects depend on each other and that's it. Put common types in a common project

Comment: Logically it doesn't make sense that some object A depends on (i.e. references) some other object B, which in turn depends on object A again. This creates a circular dependency that cannot be resolved (object A changes > object B needs rebuilding, but then it changes too > object A needs rebuilding, but then it changes again....). This sounds a bit like some kind of [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is it that you're actually trying to do?

Comment: @bassfader the problem is obvious. The error message clearly complains about the *projects* not the forms. This will appear only when *adding* a reference. The OP thought that the message refered to something else

Comment: Testing is the name of the project1 and Testing2 is the name of project2

Comment: @Pankaj did you read the message? It has nothing to do with your code. It has to do with the references you added from one project to another

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ahhh "objects" is probably the wrong term. I did not mean `System.Object` objects, but was rather trying to explain the "circular reference" thing in a generic way, so "some object A" is actually meaning one of the projects... I tried avoiding specific terms, but I guess that didn't work out as intended -.-

Comment: can anyone just give simple solution to this problem by showing actual working code ?

Comment: Thanks a lot @mjwills . the code works perfectly for my project.

Comment: @mjwills This is a circular *project* dependency. Your fiddle doesn't fix this. It doesn't happen because one property was set to something else. It happens only when you click `Add Reference` and try to reference a project that already references the current project

Comment: @mjwills I don't have to. I understand what you did, so the OP *stopped* trying to create a circular reference. The question text though is unclear. Either the question would have to be rewritten or you'd have to explain what's wrong in the answer. The fiddle isn't enough.

Comment: @mjwills it's the *entire* text that is unclear, and the error screenshot. Not just the title. Your code has nothing to do with the circular project reference.

Answer (score 0):

In `Testing2.Form1`, add a property:

```
public Form CallingForm {get; set;}
```

Then change:

```
Testing2.Form1 t2 = new Testing2.Form1();
t2.Show();
this.Hide();
```

to:

```
Testing2.Form1 t2 = new Testing2.Form1();
t2.CallingForm = this;
t2.Show();
this.Hide();
```

Then when you want to show the original form from `Testing2.Form1`, then do:

```
if (CallingForm != null)
    CallingForm.Show();
```

*This will work for your purposes - but you will be unable to actually instantiate `Testing.Form1` from `Testing2.Form1` (since that will indeed introduce a circular dependency).*